# Derivative respect to a unit vector

Tags: derivatives

What is derivative of $f(\hat{n},\vec{r})$ respect to the unit vector $\hat{n}=(cos(\phi),sin(\phi))$ ? $\phi$ is a unit vector in x_y plane.

Comment: ??? Did you mean $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking by the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of $f$ in the direction of $\hat{n}$ in the point $\vec{r}$, is defined as
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\hat{n}}(\vec{r}) =
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{r} + h\hat{n})}{h}.
$$